# Objective c method not printing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to objective c and I wanted to practice by making a simple program. For some reason the method print will not operate. Any ideas?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface person: NSObject
{
    //----Variables----
    int age;
}
    //----Methods----
    -(void) print;
    -(void)setAge: (int) a;
    @end

@implementation person
-(void) print{
    NSLog(@"You are %i years old!", age);
}
-(void) setAge: (int) a{
    age=a;
}
@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        @autoreleasepool{
         person *alex; alex = [person alloc];
         [alex setAge:12];
         [alex print];
         return 0;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- Class names should start with an uppercase letter by convention, so it should be `Person` instead of `person` everywhere.
- You *allocated* an instance of the object via `[person alloc]` (again, should be `[Person alloc]`) but you haven't *initialized* it. You need to call an initializer, as in `[[Person alloc] init]`. (In this specific case, it's not *strictly* necessary but please *always* do it nevertheless).

Apart from that, the program works. I get this in the debug console:

```
2013-10-19 15:20:10.757 Test[13551:303] You are 12 years old!
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: There is a pop-up button below the debug console with the options "All Output", "Debugger Output" and "Target Output". Make sure to set it to "All Output".

Comment: I click on that and run it again and nothing appears

Answer (score 1):

`person *alex; alex = [person alloc];` is the problem -- you never initialized the object.

`person *alex = [[person alloc] init];` is the common way to complete this.

`person *alex = [person new];` is a good shortcut (when you're using the standard `init` method only).

Comment: @user2816767 it's not clear what your comment means, but I suspect perhaps you mean it is printing correctly when you use the debugger but not otherwise? If that's your meaning -- it's because NSLog() is not intended for standard output; it goes to debug information (which lldb shows, and the Console.app application also shows). `printf()` will print to standard output.

Comment: The `new` method is actually considered to be bad style by most people I know. Avoid it.

Comment: @DarkDust can you cite a reference more peer reviewed than "most people I know"? That is... are there technical reasons to avoid `new` or is it just a matter of style preference? Clearly `new` isn't appropriate in all cases, but I've no reason to think it's never appropriate either.

Comment: Sure, just look at Apple's own code: search the Apple API reference for "new". You'll find that there are only three classes which use variants of "new": `NSObject`, `NSAtomicStore` and `NSIncrementalStore`. Then look at any framework you like, you'll have a hard time finding any use of `new`. It *is* used by some, but the majority of code clearly is avoiding it.

Comment: Oh scratch that, I've misinterpreted the search output. So, not even `NSAtomicStore` or `NSIncrementalStore` use `new` for object allocation. This means, apart from `NSObject` *no* Apple class is using `new`. You can still use the normal `new` as a shortcut for `[[Class alloc] init]` but then inconsistent to just use it sometimes. Thus easier to overlook.

Answer (score 0):

First off you need to initialize your object.

```
person *alex = [[person alloc] init];
```

Comment: lldb is the debugger. if you press "play" button until it terminates you should get a stack trace.

Comment: Where is the play button?

Comment: It's in the bottom panel.. However i copy pasted your code, without the "init fix" and it actually works out of the box weird?

Comment: @user2404543I agree that without `init` it's weird -- in your simple object it works because no initialization is apparently needed, but you should not rely on it working since on more advanced classes it will bypass class required initialization making things truly not work.